# How to permanently remove html tags from django template (filter)?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I trying to use "striptags" and "removetags:" but not quite working. Text is something like this:

```
bla, bla, bla <p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 0px; ....
```

If i use striptags or removetags with truncatewords, template completely breaks down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should clean the string first then use truncate words.. you can use regular expression to clean tags if strip_tags is not working properly.

```
import re
string = "<a href=''>abc</a>"
string = re.sub("<\!?\\\\?\/?\w+[^>]*>", "", string)
```

This regex will clean all tags opening, closing and comments tags. this is simple solution, you can make regex strict. instead of \w+ you can use (?:td|span|div...and so on) to specify which tags you want to clean.

Answer (score 1):

Either strip tags before truncating the text, or use HTML-aware `truncatewords_html`. You're operating on corrupted data if you don't.